# Creating a "Background Glow" in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I see this effect a lot in websites and feel envious because I'm like King Kong with boxing gloves on trying to operate Photoshop sometimes.

*[URL removed because it was removed and replaced with delicious snacks]*

Check this URL out, they have a brownish header background, but there is a slight white-ish glow/blur in the middle behind the actual photo. Can someone summarize or point me to a tutorial of how to achieve this in Photoshop?

Comment: up-vote for the king kong simile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the links to my original post went down, I'll reproduce the steps here:

1. Create a new document, I created a new 1000 by 250 pixel document.
2. Double click the background layer to unlock it, fill it with your desired color. I filled mine with #342f29
3. Create a new layer (Shift+Ctrl+N in Windows)
4. Set your forground color to your "glow" color. I used #8f8170
5. Select the Gradient Tool.
   Note: It may be hidden underneath your Paint Bucket Tool.
6. Select the Radial Gradient option from the toolbar.
7. Set your gradient to "Foreground To Transparent"
8. Drag your gradient wherever you want the glow to be. I wanted mine to have a "sunset" effect, so, I click and dragged from the bottom, to the top.

*Optional: Additional Glows & Texture*

1. Create a new layer (Shift+Ctrl+N in Windows)
2. Select your secondary glow color (could be the same as the first). I wanted something really subtle, so I chose #403b34
3. Changes your gradient type to Linear. Keep the gradient set to "Foreground to Transparent"
4. Drag out your gradient as desired. I just made it go from bottom to top.
5. Let's add some texture. Create a new layer.
6. Fill it with White (#ffffff)
7. Filter >> Noise >> Add Noise...
8. Press OK
9. Set the layer blending to "Darken"
10. Lower the opacity to your liking. I chose 5%

PS. I love the analogy "I'm like King Kong with boxing gloves on trying to operate Photoshop sometimes."

Comment: @benhowdle89 - No problem, I also edited in a quicker method for doing gradients. Though, once you get a hang of Photoshop, the first method shouldn't take more than 60 seconds.

Comment: The links are not working anymore... If you find some time, I'd appreaciate if you make tutorials available again.

Comment: Hey, you're right! Let me see if I can salvage this post. Though it looks like the question itself is broken too :)

Comment: I've updated my post width the text from the tutorial I posted before. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Have a play with Lighting Effects. They can be found in Filter > Render > Lighting Effects.

Looks like the one featured on your link was done with an 'Omni' light or, perhaps, a gradient fill.

Regarding gradient fills: You can choose a radial one and move the central point of it by dragging it around on your document. Have a play about with it and let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

1) Inner glow in Photoshop? Double-click on the layer to bring up the Layer Style menu and click / select "Inner Glow". Play with the settings (swapping between Center and Edge for a Source will yield wildly different results).

2) Duplicate the layer, use the gradient that Scott suggested (gradient tool with a radial gradient) and create a light gradient. Then change the gradient layer from "Normal" to Screen / Soft Light / Hard Light (depending on which one looks best to you). You can also fiddle with the opacity, so if you want a more subtle effect you can dial down the opacity.

Comment: +1 for layer styles. I like to use layer style options over manually creating shadows and gradient whenever it is possible. They can be easily toggled on and off and are very easy to duplicate for use in other part of the design (uniformity)